# Can a block that returns a boolean result be used directly in an ActiveRecord validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

If I have an attribute that I want to do a custom validation on that has a true/false result, I know I can do something such as:

```
validates_each :start_at do |record, attr, v|
  record.errors.add(attr, 'must be in the future') if v < Time.now
end
```

But it seems like overkill to have to directly access the record object in this case.  I'd like to be able to do something a bit more streamlined, such as:

```
validates :start_at, message: 'must be in the future', using: Proc.new { |v| v < Time.now }
```

or even:

```
validates_by_block(:start_at, message: 'must be in the future') { |v| v < Time.now }
```

Does Rails provide such a method or option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no support for validator like comparison in Rails. You'll have to write a custom validator yourself:

```
validates :start_at, :presence => true
validate :start_at_cannot_be_in_the_past

private
def start_at_cannot_be_in_the_past
  errors.add(:start_at, "can't be in the past") if start_at && start_at < Time.now
end
```

Comment: I appreciate the confirmation, but I don't really see the advantage of this solution over `validates_each`.

Comment: @depquid : `validates_each ` should be a preference if you have multiple attributes to validate with one condition. For example: `validates_each :first_name, :last_name do |record, attr, value|
      record.errors.add attr, 'starts with z.' if value[0] == ?z
    end` But,  if you have one attribute then making a private method and then calling it with `validate` is much more cleaner in my opinion.